# Proper way of disposing HttpclientHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version

May I know what is the proper way of disposing Handler? or should I really need to dispose it?
Because Microsoft is also diposing the Handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1

Here is my static Handler.

```
  private static HttpClientHandler handlerWithProxy = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseCookies = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
            Proxy = new WebProxy($"{MyProxy.ProxyHost}:{MyProxy.ProxyPort}", false),
            UseProxy = true,
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
        };
```

And here where I'm calling the dispose. Is it correct?

```
     private static async Task<JsonDocument> ResponseMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken token)
    {
        HttpCompletionOption option = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = MyProxy.UseProxy ? await clientWithProxy.SendAsync(request, option, token).ConfigureAwait(false)
                                                       : await client.SendAsync(request, option, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;

            using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (stream == null || stream.CanRead == false) { return default; }

                var options = new JsonDocumentOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true };
                var json = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(stream, options).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { throw new InvalidDataException($"Error occured: {ParseError(uri, json, status)}"); }

                //is this right of calling the dispose if it is already null?
                if (handler == null) { handler.Dispose(); }

                return json;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Handlers are tied to the HttpClient at creation. You don't dispose of those. Just create your HttpClient with it and forget about it. That example on MS's site is not a typical usage scenario.

Comment: Ah so meaning if I already added it to my HttpClient like this: private static readonly HttpClient clientWithProxy = new HttpClient(handlerWithProxy); there's nothing to worry about disposing?

Comment: Exactly -- You created your client exactly how it's supposed to be created. That client is static and will live the lifetime of your application, same with that single handler. You aren't leaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will be short, but sweet:

Handlers are tied to the `HttpClient` at creation. You don't dispose of those. Just create your `HttpClien`t with it and forget about it. That example on MS's site is not a typical usage scenario.

Make sure that when you create your `HttpClient` you make it static and in the class scope:

```
private static readonly HttpClient clientWithProxy = new HttpClient(handlerWithProxy);
```

You should use reuse the same `HttpClient` throughout the lifetime of your application for all HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the accepted answer. The issue with using singleton httpClientHandler.

the underlying HTTP connection might remain open against the originally DNS-resolved IP, regardless of DNS changes. This can be an issue in scenarios like blue/green deployment and DNS-based failover.

Issues of using httpClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net

So its better to use the HttpClientFactory from DI. If you requirement is such that you cant use it, you need to think about handling DNS Changes somehow. Solution proposed in this: https://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html